# Change UIImageView image whilst animating constraints

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uikit, uiimage

When attempting to change a UIImageView's image whilst animating its constraints, the image seems to momentarily glitch - the whole image rotates by 90 degrees. It then corrects itself once the animation finishes.

```
self.imageViewContainerTopConstraint.constant = 100
self.imageViewContainerLeadingConstraint.constant = 50
self.imageViewContainerTrailingConstraint.constant = 50
self.imageViewContainerBottomConstraint.constant = 100
            
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut], animations: {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)

UIView.transition(with: self.imageView, duration: 0.5, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], animations: {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "test")
}, completion: nil)
```

How can I achieve the animation of both the constraints and image without it glitching?

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**During animation:**

[image: During Animation]

Comment: Quick test -- I'm not seeing that happen. Is this an imageView? Or an imageView embedded in a view ("imageViewContainer")? Is it a layer from a camera input? Can you create a [mre]?